# Proper way of launching a new e-commerce (woocommerce) theme without losing sales?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, launching

I can't find an easy solution to launching a new woocommerce theme on a site with lots of traffic without having to go through a massive undertaking or taking the site down for a while.

The site sells wooden jewellery and gets quite a bit of traffic. We reskinned the beta copy of the wordpress site on our server and it is now ready for launch, but we can't just overwrite the old database because we will lose all of the sales between the time we made a copy of the site, and now.

Can anyone suggest a proper method of launching the beta site on the live server without losing any sales? I can't find a proper plugin that imports/exports all of the woocommerce options and products, so I'm stuck taking the site down for the whole day while I manually change everything on the live site to match the beta.... After I have to manually recreate all the sales from that day :(

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What have you changed on your test server besides theme files? Options and new products?

Comment: Are you going to change server or just want to use another Woocommerce theme?

Comment: We brought the live site to a different server to change the theme and theme options. Now we want to bring it back to live site, without overwriting the database, so we don't lose any sales. 

We changed theme files, theme options, pages, posts.